# Android to Network Signal in percentage

Tags: android

I am using the below code to calculate network signal strength.

```
class SignalStrengthListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthChanged(int asu) {
        // signalStrength = asu;
        int dbm = -113 + (2 * asu);         
    }
}
```

how i can convert dbm  to the percentage.what is lower and upper range of signal strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the value and divide by 31.

0/31 = 0. 1/31 ~ 3%. 30/31~97%.

99 is a special case which should be handled like 0.

Comment: can you please suggest lower and upper range of signal strength for device.

Comment: i have dBM value wt can i do for convert into programetically  @Adhikari

Comment: private int calculateSignalStrengthInPercent(int signalStrength) {
    return (int) ((float) signalStrength / 31 * 100);
}

Answer (score 1):

just try to explain the calculation.

just take the value suppose x .

lower limit for x is = 0

upper limit for x is = 31

now percentage = (x/31)*100;